# Working around formula 256 character limit in data validation in openpyxl module

Tags: python, excel, validation, openpyxl

I am trying to add data validation to a cell from a list of prepared strings in an openpyxl module for python.

The problem is, all the strings together take more than 256 characters limit, so data validation can't be created.

Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: It's worth noting that openpyxl doesn't actually impose a limit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of hard coding data validation as a list of strings.
EG: item1,item2,item3,item4,etc

Try doing the following:

1) Load item1,item2,item3,item4,etc into Column A of say 'Sheet3' in excel.

2) When selecting 'List' for Data Validation, use a formula.

a) Use a static formula like '=A1:A1000'. Where 1000 is your last element if your list is a fixed number of elements.

b) Use a dynamic formula if you don't know the number of elements and never want to re-adjust the data validation:

```
=OFFSET('Sheet3'!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA('Sheet3'!$A:$A) - 0,1)
```